# Exclude resource folder from WAR using Maven

Tags: maven, war

I am converting our ant build to maven using eclipse STS m2e. Now I have a problem:

I have a mapping folder under `src/main/resources` like below:

[image]

and the mapping folder has some .xml files.

Now I want to copy all the .xml files under mapping folder to `WEB-INF/classes` folder in the final WAR and for that I did this:

```
<resources>
...
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}\src\main\resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}\src\main\resources\mapping</directory>
        </resource>
...
</resources>
```

By doing this it is also creating a mapping folder in the WAR under `WEB-INF/classes`. How can I exclude this mapping folder, as all the contents are already added under `WEB-INF/classes` path directly.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you using mybatis and are those mapping folder related to mybatis? If you do not want to include the mapping folder in war then you shouldn't place it in the resources folder. Then it will be automatically ignored while creating a war file. For specifying different resource directory see this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Comment: Hi Lucky, Thanks for your comment. Yes we are placing mybatis files in the mapping folder. But I don't want to remove the mapping folder from resources. rather want to exclude using some config in pom. please advise.

Comment: You need to place those mapper xml files in a package inside `src/main/java`. eg. `com.sample.mappers` and then you need to provide the location of mapper files in the `sqlSessionFactory` bean like `<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/sample/mappers/*.xml" />`.

Comment: @Surodip Do you want to adapt Maven configuration to existing folder layout or you also accept project structure modification? Because answer may simple: if you want some file on resource root `/` then put then on root instead of `mapping`

Comment: @michaldo5 - yes I want to adapt Maven configuration to existing folder layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes><exclude>mapping/</exclude></excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/mapping</directory>
        </resource>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have tried something like this, but that was incorrect.This is what I needed.

Comment: @Surodip Nice. I also migrate Ant to Maven and apply tricks like this still.